# Template might not exists

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Im trying to call restapi and im getting error

```
package czajka.piotr.restapi.viewcontroller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class FieldViewController {

    @RequestMapping("/view-fields")
    public String viewFields()
    {
        return "view-fields";
    }
}
```

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [view-fields], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
> at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:869) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:607) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:366) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1400) ~
> etc

properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/serverdb?useUnicode=true&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=12345678
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
server.port=8081
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML5
```

[Maybe this would help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeA6K.png)

Comment: Do you have a file `templates/view-fields.html` on your classpath ?

Comment: Oh thanks. I had field named fields-view.html, i renamed to view-fields.html and started working. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [your ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeA6K.png) you have named the template as `field-view.html` but in  controller you are returning `view-fields`.

Your code :

```java
package czajka.piotr.restapi.viewcontroller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class FieldViewController {

    @RequestMapping("/view-fields")
    public String viewFields()
    {
        return "field-view";
    }
}
```

Btw when you are making **rest api** you should use **@RestController** annotation instead of @Controller. Actually **Controller** will look for temples and **RestController** will return actual string or you can write html code too.